# github client stuck at 256 files to be commited even though it syncs

Tags: git, github

A colleague  of mine worked on our project and uploaded his changed files to our ftp server without using git.

So i downloaded the entire FTP directory to my documents/github/project directory and ran the git-hub client. It shows there are 256 changes that need to be made, i provide a commit message and hit sync and it shows its syncing, but after its done it still shows there are 256 files to be committed. I've tried to commit several times and sync but still stuck at 256 files to be committed.

What can I do so the 256 changed files on my PC are synced with Git-hub?

Comment: Are you using some GUI or is this on CLI? Also do you want to commit all changed files?

Comment: i use the github windows client, but if i need to type something in the shell to fix it, i can do that.

Comment: yes i wanna commit all files that he changed so they show up at gitub, so we can revert any if need be.

Comment: `git add -A && git commit -m "My colleague sucks" && git push`

Comment: HAHAHA I LOVE IT! and it worked!

Comment: Let me add it as an answer and please tell your colleague to start using version control :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to stage all files for commit you can do:

```
git add -A
```

This stages all files for commit. After this you can commit the staged files:

```
git commit -m "My colleague sucks"
```

And finally you can push it to github using:

```
git push
```

Or in a single line:

```
git add -A && git commit -m "My colleague sucks" && git push
```